# Filtering arguments through an argument, why will this not work?

Tags: javascript

I want to remove all the `arguments` from the `array` passed in function `destroyer` which was passed as `arguments`.

```
function destroyer(arr) {

    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); //turns arguments into arrays

    function checkArgs() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < args.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == args[j]) {
                    delete arr[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return arr.filter(checkArgs);
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3); //Remove 2nd, 3rd, etc arguments from first argument...??
```

Comment: Why not `var args = Array.from(arguments);`?

Comment: Note that `arguments` contains *all* the arguments to the function, including `arr`.

Comment: @connexo for optimization reasons it's not a good idea to pass `arguments` out of a function. It's better to perform the copy with a plain `for` loop. (That said, yes `Array.from()` would be better.)

Comment: Note that deleting from an array is something you should usually not do (applying `delete` to an array)

Comment: Using both `.filter()` and also deleting elements in the filter callback doesn't make sense. The filter callback should be returning `true` or `false`, and the result of filtering the array will be a *new* array. The `delete` is going to mess up your iteration anyway, because you always increment `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.filter` callback requires you to `return` what should be in the filtered result.

From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**:

> **Return value**
>
> A new array with the elements that pass the test. If no
>   elements pass the test, an empty array will be returned.

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // turns arguments into arrays

    function checkArgs() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < args.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] == args[j]) {
                    delete arr[i];
                }
            }
        }
        // You have to return something in the filter callback
        return arr;
    }

    return arr.filter(checkArgs);
}

//remove 2nd, 3rd, etc arguments from first argument
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 3));
```

Comment: Another problem is that the code is using `filter()` *and* the filter callback is deleting elements itself. That really makes no sense.

Comment: @Pointy True, but I decided to stick to the question of why the code wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The `.filter` require a `return` value as a filtered value. And also `argumnents` also contains the `array arr`  at position `0` so you have to start from position `1`.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); //turns arguments into arrays
function checkArgs() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j < args.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == args[j]) {
                delete arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
return arr;
}
return arr.filter(checkArgs);
}
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a slightly simplified version for the filter. There are other ways you can optimize this as well. This is assuming a 0-based index.

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // turns arguments into arrays

    return args[0].filter(function(item, index) {     
       return args.indexOf(index) < 0;
    });
}

//remove 2nd, 3rd, etc arguments from first argument
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Comment: This provides an alternate solution, but doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: That's true. I got too focused on the `checkArgs()` function.